Help with coupled PDE using NDSolve
I have been working on solving a PDE that models the generation, recombination, and diffusion of charge carriers in a semiconductor. Essentially, this involves solving a continuity equation that is coupled with an additional PDE describing a specific kinetic event.
To simplify the problem, I initially focused on solving the continuity equation with diffusion, without the second PDE.
The constant parameters are as follows:
d = 380*10^-6; (*m*)
d2 = 100*10^-9; (*m*)
Io = 1000;(*W/m2*)
\[Alpha] = 
  53500;(*1/m at 800 nm wavelenght that is photon energy 1.55 eV*)
No = (1 - 0.32)*
   Io/1.458/(1.6*10^-19)/(6.02214*10^23);(*incident mols photons at the surface (m2*ms)*)
\[Tau]eff = 10*10^-6 ;(*s*)
G[x_] := \[Alpha]*No*
  Exp[-\[Alpha]*
    x] (* generation rate excited electrons/(m3*s) *)
Plot[G[x] \[Tau]eff, {x, 0, d}, PlotRange -> All]
Dn = 0.003598;(*m2/s*)

The PDE is
diffusionPDE = 
  D[u[t, x], t] - Dn*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] - 
   HeavisideTheta[t - 0.2]*G[x] + u[t, x]/\[Tau]eff;
domain = {0, d};
timedomain = {0, 1};
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], N] = NeumannValue[0, x == domain[[1]]];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D] = 
  DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 0, x == domain[[2]]];

ufun = NDSolveValue[{
   diffusionPDE == Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], N], 
   Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D], u[0, x] == 0},
  u, {t, timedomain[[1]], timedomain[[2]]}, {x, domain[[1]], 
   domain[[2]]}]

Plot3D[{ufun[t, x]}, {t, timedomain[[1]], timedomain[[2]]}, {x, 
  domain[[1]], domain[[2]]}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MaxRecursion -> 10, Mesh -> 10]

Which solves pretty quickly. The 3D plot of the generated solution is

The additional PDE, D[w(t,x),t], is then coupled to the diffusionPDE as shown below.
diffusionPDE = 
  D[u[t, x], t] - Dn*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] - 
   HeavisideTheta[t - 0.2]*G[x] + u[t, x]/\[Tau]eff + 
   HeavisideTheta[x - d2]*D[w[t, x], t]/d2;

domain = {0, d};
timedomain = {0, 1};
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], N] = NeumannValue[0, x == domain[[1]]];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D] = 
  DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 0, x == domain[[2]]];

ufun = NDSolveValue[{
   diffusionPDE == Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], N], 
   Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D], u[0, x] == 0,
   D[w[t, x], t] == -HeavisideTheta[t - 0.5]*10^0*w[t, x]*u[t, x]*d2, 
   w[0, x] == 0.0001},
  {u, w}, {t, timedomain[[1]], timedomain[[2]]}, {x, domain[[1]], 
   domain[[2]]}]


Plot3D[ufun[[1]][t, x], {t, timedomain[[1]], timedomain[[2]]}, {x, 
  domain[[1]], domain[[2]]}, PlotRange -> All]

The expected solution to this coupled PDE should produce a 3D plot qualitatevely resembling the one below,

However, the computation of the solution is extremely slow and highly sensitive to the "time domain." For very short time domains (e.g., hundreds of microseconds), I can obtain a reasonable solution. Unfortunately, the experimental conditions I am modeling occur on the scale of seconds, and I have not been able to successfully solve the coupled PDE under these conditions.
Any assistance in addressing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

A bit too long for the comment:
Replace every HeavisideTheta with a
stepFun[a_] := UnitStep[a]

That's not going to solve you problem, but you can experiment with different  step functions. HeavisideTheta is a distribution, might not be ideal for this.
Then add an EvaluationMonitor, then you at least know where in the integration you are. Something like this:
Monitor[ufun = NDSolveValue[{
    diffusionPDE == Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], N], 
    Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D], u[0, x] == 0, 
    D[w[t, x], t] == -stepFun[t - 0.5]*10^-2*w[t, x]*u[t, x]*d2 + 
      0.0001,
    w[0, x] == 0.0001
    }
   , {u, w}, {t, timedomain[[1]], timedomain[[2]]}, {x, domain[[1]], 
    domain[[2]]}, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])], monitor]

Note, that you initial condition for w and the equation are not consistent at t==0, so I added +0.0001 from the ic and I also introduced an arbitrary coefficient. When you look at the monitor you see that the slowness starts at 0.2. This comes from the coupling of u into the w equation.
I think this is just the way things are and you have to wait for the time integration to finish. But with the monitor you now know where you are at.

Thank you for your comment—this has been incredibly helpful. Adding the "EvaluationMonitor" confirmed one of my suspicions: the sampling step size used by NDSolveValue is very fine (10^−6 seconds) compared to the time scales of interest in my model. If the slowness is inherently due to the coupling of u into w, is there a way to increase the step size used by NDSolve for evaluating the PDE solution? Ideally, I would like the step size to be on the order of 10^−3 seconds rather than 10^−6.

I attempted to use a combination of MaxStepFraction and MaxStepSize, but these settings only seem to work effectively for values of t before the step function begins at 0.2. Once NDSolve evaluates the solution for t > 0.2, the sampling reverts to the 10^−6 scale and appears to ignore the MaxStepFraction and MaxStepSize settings.

No, you can not increase the step size - for very good reason: It would deliver the wrong solution. You can, however, lower the AccuracyGoal and/or PrecisionGoal but even then I guess the time steps will be small. Probably because the PDE just requires that.
